# How can I delete my account?

Tags: support, status-completed

After due consideration I don't think I can enjoy this forum.

How could I delete my account profile if possible.

Comment: https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account

Comment: @Carpetsmoker the option isn't there. What can I do?

Comment: Use the "contact us" button at the bottom of the page on the right. You can't delete if you have questions and voted (this is to prevent certain types of voting fraud and the like).

Answer (score 1):

As Carpetsmoker wrote in the comments: [Instructions for deleting your account can be found in the help center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account).

When you haven't posted anything yet, you can delete your account in your profile account settings.

When you already have content on the site, [you need to contact the Stackexchange team](https://politics.stackexchange.com/contact).